# A question regarding a paragraph.

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image: Refer to this picture for the paragraph]

There's this paragraph here, and the question reads:

"The first people who invented a system of drains and plumbing are the..."

I'm convinced that the answer is People of The Secret Cities whilst people tell me it's the Romans,

If it is the Romans, can I have an explanation to why?

Comment: If no one knows where these cities "disappeared to", how can anyone know what kind of plumbing they had?

Comment: You're right, the inverted commas in"'first invented' by the Romans" imply that, whilst it is commonly said that they first invented plumbing, that is not true.

Comment: This is a bad question. The author of the paragraph thinks that the people of the "Secret Cities" **built** drains and plumbing before the Romans, but the author doesn't actually say that the people of the "Secret Cities" **invented,** or were **the first to invent,** a system of drains and plumbing. The passage as written is entirely consistent with the idea that some third group of people even older than the Romans and the people of the "Secret Cities" were the first to invent a system of drains and plumbing.

Comment: Sorry, Saitama. Interpretation of passages ('comprehension') is off-topic on ELU. As choster expresses clearly,the ELU Q&A format is designed to answer specific, narrowly-focused questions, and is not well-suited to interpreting articles or passages. You are strongly encouraged to take the site tour and review the help center for additional guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are right, it isn't the Romans, according to this passage.

The point the passage is making is that while the Romans are *generally thought* to be the inventors of this level of plumbing technology, the people of the Secret Cities actually had them 2,500 years earlier than the Romans did.

The quotes around "first invented" are [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) implying irony, in the same way that they'd be used in a sentence reading, "When Columbus 'discovered' America, he ...", the point there being that he can't have discovered America when it was already inhabited by people who'd arrived there before he did, and had been visited by the Vikings 400 or 500 years before his arrival.

One might suggest that "discovered" and "invented" can mean "from the point of view of a particular population that didn't know about them before". If the Romans figured out plumbing without having had any idea that it had existed somewhere else in the world centuries earlier, and the technology as *the Romans* developed it is what spread throughout the rest of the world, leading directly to the technology of plumbing as we know it today, then the Romans "invented" it in *that* sense of the word. Likewise, if the pre-Columbian residents of the New World never returned to the Old World and spread news about the New World (and possibly didn't even realize it had never been known to humankind before), and if word from the Vikings didn't really get around, so that, as far as most of the world knew at the time, Columbus's expeditions were the source of this knowledge that then spread widely, then Columbus was the "discoverer" in that sense.

But in the sense of "first people ever to create", the Romans weren't the inventors.